# NUnit's TestResult.xml displayed nicely?

Tags: html, unit-testing, nunit, format

Im running the `nunit-console` program to test some assemblies after the build script is run. The `TestResult.xml` is then copied to a static web server.

Im looking for a tool that could format the xml output into a nice html page that displays the results similar to how the NUnit GUI does it. Im looking for a color coded hierarchal display for easy scanning if something failed.

Anyone know of such a tool? Or maybe Im missing something in the docs and NUnit can already do what I ask for.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how useful it will be for you, but the only thing I can think of at the moment are the xsl stylesheets distributed as part of CruiseControl.net. You can download it from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/CruiseControl.NET%201.5/

if you go for the zip file, the xsl is in /WebDashboard/xsl/tests.xsl (if I remember correctly)

Comment: Seems to be what Im looking for. Then I just need a simple and nice xsl processor. You dont happen to know one?

Comment: Using this .net implementation (http://www.saxonica.com/), but apparently its a 2.0 processor and the style is 1.0.